# I would like...or I wish - talking about possible improvement in the future

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, wish

I have somehow got confused with the usage of **'I would like'** and **'I wish'** when talking about the things which could be possible to improve in the future. I read several posts here and on the Internet, also checked the dictionary, but I am still confused.

For example, the context could be the following: I stay at the accommodation, and the bathroom doesn't have any shelves to put my toiletries on.
Could I write any of these sentences as feedback for the place? Could you explain what do you understand with the sentences I have written below?

1. I would like to have shelves in the bathroom.
2. I would like shelves in the bathroom.
3. I wish there were shelves in the bathroom.
4. I wish there would be shelves in the bathroom.

I am confused because I was taught that 'I wish there was/were' is usually used about something that is not possible/is very unlikely to happen.
The phrase 'I would like' would be something I would like to have or do at the certain moment. Could it be used as some sort of advice and not mean that I want the shelves in my bathroom?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an old saying, ***If wishes were horses, beggars would ride***. Stereotypical beggars always wish for things they haven't got - and are never likely to get, because stereotypical beggars tend to waste their time idly *wishing* for things (to be given to them) rather than doing whatever is necessary to actually ***get*** them.

That example shows how we *usually* assume that ***wishes*** often don't come true. So *I wish you gave me presents* implies you ***don't*** give me presents (and possibly never will), and *I wish it was Christmas* implies it's ***not*** Christmas (though in *that* case, obviously it ***will*** be Christmas sooner or later).

Saying what you ***want*** (or ***would like***) carries no particular implications as to how likely it is that you'll get what you want (that depends entirely on other aspects of the context).

---

If OP wants to express the idea that in some "generic" sense it ***would be better*** if there were more shelves, but that he isn't so bothered about this as to actually ***want*** them himself, he could say...

> 5: ***There should be / ought to be*** more shelves in the bathroom
>    or perhaps
>    6: ***You ought to have*** more shelves in the bathroom (if it's the addressee's bathroom, not the speaker's)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! If I may go back to my sentences - if I say 'I wish there were shelves..' --> I just state the fact that there were no shelves and probably never will. But how about - 'I wish there would be shelves...'? Does it maybe express some kind of more realistic wish which doesn't exclude the possibility to come true? Is 'I would like' usage appropriate at all in the context I described? Regarding 'I would like', my focus is not so much on whether it will be fulfilled, only just to express the wish, so the owner would know it. Your suggestions are very appropriate!

Comment: I don't consider *I wish there would be shelves* to be idiomatically valid English (it should be subjunctive *I wish there **were** shelves*). But I think you're expecting too much of ordinary English here. Sure, you can tell your landlord ***what you want*** - but how likely that is to actually ***happen*** is up to him (it doesn't really depend on how you express your wishes to him). But maybe you could consider saying *I **expect** shelves* (I think that's ***likely***, because I ***demand*** them) or *I **don't suppose there could be** shelves?* (I doubt it, but *maybe* there's a chance).

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers for your time and help here! I really appreciate it! Have a wonderful Sunday evening! :-)